# Реализация разных контролов в ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

Есть `ItemsControl`

```
        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--здесь должен 1 из 3 контролов-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Все элементы в массиве, на который подвязан это ItemsControl унаследованы от одного класса.
Но есть необходимость для каждого из типов  использовать свой контрол, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM1}">
            <!--здесь кладёте 1-ый контрол -->
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM2}">
            <!--здесь кладёте 2-ой контрол -->
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:VM3}">
            <!--здесь кладёте 3-ий контрол -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Свойство `ItemTemplate` не устанавливайте.

Comment: благодарю! очень быстро)

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Пожалуйста!